# I was not able to open my wordpress in a local host properly

Tags: wordpress

How can i open the word press web site which is not able to open at all it has been directed to the other page and i could not able to see even the log in page in a proper way it is showing the page not found exception in my wordpress

Comment: Are you running Apache on your machine?

Comment: We don't have magic ball; we can't know how you config your WordPress. Thus, you should give more information about how you config & the server settings.

Comment: wamp server when i was log in it is directing to other page

Comment: Please provide more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me you have an issue with .htaccess, but can't be sure because we need more information about your config.